# Observable.next() breaks loop

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

This piece of code parses triples (not that important) and should return one parking at a time. The problem is that calling observer.next() breaks the loop as it just runs once. The console.log also doesn't get called. I'm probably missing something but is it possible that observer.next() breaks the loop? Is there an error or is it a feature or am I just plain wrong?

```
 return Observable.create(observer => {
  this.fetch.get(datasetUrl).then(response => {
    // Get all subjects that are parkings
    const parkingTriples = [],
      parkings = [],
      totalspacesParking = [],
      labels = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < response.triples.length; index++) {
      if (response.triples[index].object === 'http://vocab.datex.org/terms#UrbanParkingSite') {
        parkingTriples.push(response.triples[index]);
      }
      if (response.triples[index].predicate === 'http://vocab.datex.org/terms#parkingNumberOfSpaces') {
        totalspacesParking.push(response.triples[index]);
      }
      if (response.triples[index].predicate === 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label') {
        labels.push(response.triples[index]);
      }
    }
    const _parkings = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < parkingTriples.length; index++) {
      const totalspacesresult = find(totalspacesParking, (o) => {
        return o.subject === parkingTriples[index].subject
      });
      const totalspaces = parseInt(n3.Util.getLiteralValue(totalspacesresult.object), 10);
      const labelresult = find(labels, (o) => {
        return o.subject === parkingTriples[index].subject
      });
      const rdfslabel = n3.Util.getLiteralValue(labelresult.object);
      const id = rdfslabel.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
      observer.next(new Parking(rdfslabel, parkingTriples[index].subject, id, totalspaces, datasetUrl));
      console.log(observer);
    }

  })
})
```

Comment: Can you simplify your problem / provide a testcase? In general `observer.next()` should not break your code

Comment: @MarkvanStraten `for (let index = 0; index < parkingTriples.length; index++) {
      observer.next();
      console.log('I still get hit through');
    }  `

Comment: what is the signature of `observer`? When using a regular `Rx.Subject` your simplified testcase will work

Comment: @MarkvanStraten I updated the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your updated code I would suggest debugging it. Most likely the bug is not in the Rx bits. I have refactored your code to split between the Rx logic and the response parsing:

```
function getParkings(datasetUrl){
  return Rx.Observable.defer(() => this.fetch.get(datasetUrl))
    .mergeMap(response => parseParkingResponse(response));
}

function parseParkingResponse(response) {
  const parkingTriples = [],
    parkings = [],
    totalspacesParking = [],
    labels = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < response.triples.length; index++) {
    if (response.triples[index].object === 'http://vocab.datex.org/terms#UrbanParkingSite') {
      parkingTriples.push(response.triples[index]);
    }
    if (response.triples[index].predicate === 'http://vocab.datex.org/terms#parkingNumberOfSpaces') {
      totalspacesParking.push(response.triples[index]);
    }
    if (response.triples[index].predicate === 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label') {
      labels.push(response.triples[index]);
    }
  }

  const _parkings = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < parkingTriples.length; index++) {
    const totalspacesresult = find(totalspacesParking, (o) => {
      return o.subject === parkingTriples[index].subject
    });
    const totalspaces = parseInt(n3.Util.getLiteralValue(totalspacesresult.object), 10);
    const labelresult = find(labels, (o) => {
      return o.subject === parkingTriples[index].subject
    });
    const rdfslabel = n3.Util.getLiteralValue(labelresult.object);
    const id = rdfslabel.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase();
    _parkings.push(new Parking(rdfslabel, parkingTriples[index].subject, id, totalspaces, datasetUrl));
  }

  return _parkings;
}
```

This will make it easier to debug what is going on.

Comment: This code works! But it's streaming the array. I want to stream every parking  one after the other and call oberserver.next(new Parking()) in the loop itself

Comment: unless you are doing something async with the Parking items the `parseParkingResponse` will be sync so streaming them will not be any different

Answer (score 1):

In general a `Subject` will not break your code. Given the following:

```js
const observer = new Rx.Subject();
const parkingTriples = new Array(10);

observer.subscribe(val => console.log('value emitted: ' + val));

for (let index = 0; index < parkingTriples.length; index++) {
  observer.next(index); 
  console.log('I still get hit through'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

This will emit `I still get hit through` every time. Most likely the `observer` is undefined in your code so invoking `observer.next()` breaks and the following `console.log` is never seen.